# Count on tag return nothing in CnosDB

Tags: sql, cnosdb

I am confused why CnosDB show such behavior when I am trying to count on a tag. It doesn't return any error or return any info.

I am using the sample database from [the doc](https://cnosdb.github.io/docs/content/cnosdb/latest/cnosql/cnosql_sample.html).

The data looks as follows:

```
> select * from test_air
name: test_air
time                         pressure station     temperature visibility
----                         -------- -------     ----------- ----------
2022-07-01T08:42:04.4103282Z 75       XiaoMaiDao  79          68
2022-07-01T08:42:09.6582015Z 78       LianYunGang 63          71
2022-07-01T08:43:24.5802497Z 79       LianYunGang 63          71
2022-07-01T08:43:24.6005666Z 79       LianYunGang 53          71
2022-07-01T08:43:24.6228182Z 90       LianYunGang 63          71
2022-07-01T08:43:24.6451171Z 75       XiaoMaiDao  79          78
2022-07-01T08:43:25.2744992Z 75       XiaoMaiDao  77          78
2022-07-05T11:34:04.8420635Z          XiaoMaiDao  70          85
```

And I am doing count on all columns now:

```
> select count(*) from test_air
name: test_air
time                 count_pressure count_temperature count_visibility
----                 -------------- ----------------- ----------------
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 7              8                 8
```

And I am doing counting for a field:

```
> select count(*) from test_air
name: test_air
time                 count_pressure count_temperature count_visibility
----                 -------------- ----------------- ----------------
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 7              8                 8
```

And I am doing counting for another field:

```
> select count(temperature) from test_air
name: test_air
time                 count
----                 -----
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 8
```

**However, it doesn't return any info for counting on a tag:**

```
> select count(station) from test_air
>
```

Shouldn't it return 2 as there are 2 values in the tag set: XiaoMaiDao and LianYunGang?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: thx for the suggestion. I am trying to test this CnosDB (https://cnosdb.github.io/docs/content/cnosdb/latest/about.html) against InfluxDB. seems there is no CnosDB yet ;(